# Is there such a notion of "expansion" in groups?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Given a subset of elements of a finite group $G$, I would like it to be such that the set of all distinct words (as elements of $G$) that can be formed from this set is exponentially large in the size of the set. I would say that such a set is ``exponentially expanding"

Are existence of such sets in groups characterized in some way? 
Is there some standard terminology for this?

What is known?

Comment: What's the precise condition you want to study? As the group is finite, you surely don't want to asymptotic estimates involving constants, do you? For infinite groups, and more generally, infinite dimensional algebras, you might find http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Growth_rate_%28group_theory%29 and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand%E2%80%93Kirillov_dimension interesting.

Comment: @Hanno Your link about "Growth Rate" seems to apply to finite groups - right?

Comment: On the contrary, growth rate is only relevant for infinite groups. But there is a notion of expansion in finite groups. Try this link for references: http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~laci/papers/bnp-soda08.pdf

Comment: @DerekHolt But doesn't the wiki link on growth rate (above) say that every free group of rank k > 1 has an exponential growth rate - this seems like a statement for finite groups - right?

Comment: How can a statement about free groups be a statement about finite groups?

Comment: Ah - okay! - so thats what I am misreading - so can a finite group has such an exponential expansion property?

Comment: No, any finite group will clearly have constant growth.

Comment: OP: I don't know much about the area myself, but you might want to read this: https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/eberhard/expanders.pdf